# Where are the location settings on Asus ZenFone 5?

Tags: settings, location-services, asus-zenfone-5

I can't find the GPS settings on the ZenFone 5 (ZE620KL), on Android 9. I am specifically interested in the location mode, with 3 different values (high accuracy, battery saving, device only).

Asus has rolled out Android 9 to ZenFone 5. I don't have a Security & Location entry in the Settings menu. Here is what my Settings menu looks like and once in Security & lock screen:

[image] [image]
<sub>(source: [digitaltrends.com](https://icdn9.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends/asus_zenfone_5z_notch_1-1080x2246.jpg))</sub>

I can't find where to choose the location mode. All I have is an ON/OFF switch.

Comment: Your phone should run Android 8 hence it is located Security & Location -> Location -> Location -> Mode - see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3467281?hl=en#zippy=%2Cchoose-location-mode-android

Comment: @Robert, please see my edit

Comment: I see "Security & lock screen .... Location". So why don't you use this entry? Alternatively, use the settings search (the magnifying glas up right) and enter "location".

Comment: Thank you both, I honestly didn't see it when I searched. My phone is set to French and If I hadn't changed the language to make a screenshot, it wouldn't have been shown, as it would have been buried further down. And I didn't think it had anything to do with some services with some google logo on it, so my quick glance didn't catch it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578575/androids-most-accurate-location-api

Comment: i am german native speaker but when it comes to devices (linux pc, android phone) i prefer english gui, that make things easier as most tutorials are english. also searching for english error messages is more sufficient :)